# Two words in a video

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I have watched this video hundreds of times but there are two words I still can't figure out what they are. They have been bugging me and I would really appreciate if anyone could let me know what those two words are.

Link to video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMxiGI7Rhlo

(1) Between 1:05 and 1:10, between "it's only 1:0 at that point" and "the whole thing is a mess" there is a word that pronounces like "knee-dure" ("dure" like in "procedure") being said by both guys several times, what is that word?

(2) Between 2:36 and 2:48, between "who are people like me" and "listen, hold on", the guy wearing the red hat says "are you xxx at me" several time, the word sounds like "work-a-meat" or something similar, what is that word?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific and not likely to be generally useful information.

Comment: That's true, if possible how can I close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first word around the one minute mark is "knee-jerk", and is repeated by the interviewee.

I think the second is "tell me who I am, then. Are you more committed than me?"

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that. All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1) The phrase is [*knee-jerk*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knee%E2%80%93jerk).

2) I can't figure that one out, either.